# Algorithms for determining where to go next

Tags: algorithm, optimization, fifo

I recently started a project where I have to design an algorithm for a warehouse. Consider the following scenario.

A warehouse worker is walking with a trolley, looking at his handheld terminal to see which product he has to pick off the shelf and put on the trolley. Right now, the order of products being picked is working on a FIFO algorithm - which ever order came in first is the one to be picked first.

What I would like to do is the following:
I would like to implement an algorithm that goes over the orders and checks which orders are closest to each other so that the worker does not have to move to 6 different locations, but instead picks 5 orders in the same location and then moves on to another location. 
This will require me knowing how far the different products are from each other and choosing the ones closest to the first order chosen.

I am hoping someone knows of any algorithms I could start researching and brushing up on. Thank you.

Comment: I believe your problem is equivalent to the travel salesman problem, which does not have a good optimal solution, but has many good heuristics and/or approximate solutions. It is well-studied problem so a google search will take you very far.

Comment: @9mat thank you! I'll give it a look and hopefully it will solve my problem.! Can you mark comments as solutions?